# Bootstrap How to pass data from row td items

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Have following code as below what i would like to achieve is to show data from each td's values into the modal window when user click on specific row. Currently i am stack and don't know how to achieve that - i tried to add data-id and modal class to each td's but this one is not working also don't know what to put inside JS and modal. Plase of your help.

JS:

```
   $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var getIdFromRow = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
        $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Information for LP: ' + getIdFromRow + '</b>'))
    });
```

Modal:

```
@<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="orderDetails">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And razor's for each loop data: (i added data id and class modal to each td but its not good, can you help me out) ? :

```
...
     @For Each item In Model.Transports
           Dim currentItem = item
            @<tr>

        <td class="col-lg-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="1">@item.Lp</td>
        <td class="col-lg-1  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="2">@item.Name</td>
        <td class="col-lg-1  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="3">@item.Surname</td
....
```

**EDIT for further discussions:**

```
...
    @For Each item In Model.Transports
       Dim currentItem = item
          @<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editinvModal">



    <td class="col-lg-1" data-id="lp">@item.Lp</td>
    <td class="col-lg-1" data-id="DataPrzyjazdu">@item.DataPrzyjazdu</td>
....
```

**Modal:**

```
@<div class="modal fade" id="editinvModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Selected row information</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- Lp -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p class="form-control" title="Selected row's lp'" id="lp1" name="lp"></p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Date -->
                    <div class="form-group input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i></span>
                        <input readonly class="form-control form_datetime" name="date" id="date1" type="text">
                    </div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer ">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <button name="cancel" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Ok
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#editinvModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget); //button that triggered the modal

            var lp = button.data('lp');
            var date = button.data('DataPrzyjazdu');

            var modal = $(this);

            modal.find('.modal-body #lp1').val(lp);
            modal.find('.modal-body #date1').val(date);
        });

        $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            minView: 2,
            pickTime: false,
            autoclose: true,
            todayBtn: true
        });
    });
```

Comment: It works here - http://jsfiddle.net/w3ztfbn1/

Comment: Side note: you can use `data` instead `attr` like `var getIdFromRow = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id');` and make sure the script is DOM ready

Comment: i want to take all three values at once - i mean if user will click some row then he should see those data in modal like lp value, Name value and Surname value. You see what i mean? put some solution as answer if any

Comment: add more data attributes contains data and pass it like `data-id` see this question and answer also check fiddles in answer how to pass multiple data values to modal and show http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280203/modal-form-clearing-when-a-field-is-selected/34280505#34280505

Comment: Hi Shehery - can you please check my main post - EDIT section - i am still fighting with that can you tell me whats wrong there?

Comment: when to message someone on SO in comments make sure put `@` sign before username like @JohnDoe so that user get notified

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Base on OP's comment

*What I really want is user to click some specific tr and then modal will show all it's `td's` data in modal*

In HTML

To pass one or more then one value (personally tested upto 15 values) to Modal using `data` attribute,

```
data-id="item.Lp1"
data-name="item.Name1"
data-surname="item.Surname1"
```

can add more but make sure each `data` attribute name is unique

```
<table>
  <tr data-id="item.Lp1" data-name="item.Name1" data-surname="item.Surname1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <td class="col-lg-1">item.Lp1</td>
    <td class="col-lg-1">item.Name1</td>
    <td class="col-lg-1">item.Surname1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="item.Lp2" data-name="item.Name2" data-surname="item.Surname2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <td class="col-lg-1">item.Lp2</td>
    <td class="col-lg-1">item.Name2</td>
    <td class="col-lg-1">item.Surname2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="item.Lp3" data-name="item.Name3" data-surname="item.Surname3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <td class="col-lg-1">item.Lp3</td>
    <td class="col-lg-1">item.Name3</td>
    <td class="col-lg-1">item.Surname3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In JS (modal event listener)

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'); //<- It's data-id value
    var name = $(e.relatedTarget).data('name'); //<- It's data-name value
});
```

Now if you want to pass the variables `var` values to input, you can do

```
$("#selector1").val(id);
$("#selector2").val(name);
```

OR if you want to pass the the variables `var` values to HTML, you can do

```
$("#selector1").html(id);
$("#selector2").html(name);
```

Final JS will be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'); //<- It's data-id value
    var name = $(e.relatedTarget).data('name'); //<- It's data-name value
     var surname = $(e.relatedTarget).data('surname'); //<- It's data-surname value  

    $("#selector1").val(id); //<- Passing to input only
    $("#selector2").html(name); //Passing to HTML only
    $("#selector3").val(surname); //Passing to Input only
 });
});
```

Now in Modal, add `selectors`

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        To pass value to input
        <input type="text" id="selector1" name="selector1" value="">
        <br> To pas value to HTML
        <div id="selector2"></div>
        <br> To pass value to input
        <input type="text" id="selector3" name="selector3" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SideNote: Remember `# Ids` must be unique throughout the document

Fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/b9qje9je/3/) based on above code

Comment: but now its obligatory user to click on specific td within specific tr. What i really want is user to click some specific tr and then modal will show all it's td's data in modal. How change to that? And in you fiddle it should take not lp1, lp2 and lp3 but their values (so item.Lp, item.Name)

Comment: code in answer updated so as fiddle example, the logic was same, just need to move the `data` attribute from `td` to `tr` and that's all